# How to remove all resharper keybindings?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I like resharper fine, but with the new pricing, the trial ran out and I want to try life without it.

Except after disabling all the Resharper commands are still bound in my keyboard options! So <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd> doesn't fall back to the standard VS behavior because its bound to `Resharper.Resharper_GotoRecentEdits` which is, of course, disabled.

Even clicking Reset in the keyboard options does not remove the keybindings.
So what the heck. How do I get rid of all the resharper stuff? It is currently suspended and doesn't have a menu item.

This is Visual Studio 2015 with Resharper Ultimate trial

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling ReSharper?

Comment: @meh-uk ah. That finally worked. Didn't realize that I had to do that *in addition to disabling resharper*.

Comment: Cool. I've added it as an answer in case you want to give me the bounty, but @fabio-salvalai's answer looks good too - as at least it doesn't require an uninstall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following steps worked for me:

- Disable ReSharper
- In ReSharper's options -> Keyboard & Menus, select the `Visual Studio` scheme and click on `Apply Scheme`.
- Mind the note under the Apply Scheme button: Click save to close the ReSharper Dialog and...
- In TOOLS --> Options | Keyboard, make sure the right mapping scheme is selected (Visual C# 2005 for me) and click `Reset` and finally, `Ok`

That did the trick for me. opening the keyboard dialog once again and hitting `Ctrl+,` in the Press shortcut keys was no longer showing the key mapping to be bound to `Resharper.Resharper_GotoRecentEdits`

Comment: I was unable to disable or uninstall Resharper for some reason. However, inside the Resharper options I was able to disable Resharper; that, plus choosing an alternate layout (beside "Default") worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment on the initial post - it seems sometimes you have to uninstall ReSharper to remove the key bindings.